# На точке или в точке?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно писать, говорить: "на торговой точке" или "в торговой точке"?

Comment: Побольше бы контекста. Текст приведите в котором вы хотите употребить эту фразу

Comment: Вариант  "в торговой точке" 10 примеров 
 https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Ck4qGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCKwopCicKA3JlcRIgCh7QsiDRgtC%2B0YDQs9C%2B0LLQvtC5INGC0L7Rh9C60LUwAQ==  А варианта "на торговой точке" там нет.  ТОЧКА  6. Место, пункт, в котором расположено или происходит что-л. Радиотрансляционная т. Оборонительная т. Огневая т. Торговая т. (ПРОФ.; магазин, ларёк).

Comment: И. Грекова. Дамский мастер (1963)  — А я прекращаю работу в этой точке, — ответил он, — и возвращаюсь на свою старую точку. Почему не пользовались НКРЯ? Национа́льный ко́рпус ру́сского языка́ (НКРЯ) — доступный для поиска электронный онлайн-корпус русскоязычных текстов. Корпус открыт 29 апреля 2004 года. Некоторые участники форума вроде бы активно использовали, ссылки есть. –

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не говорила ни так, ни так. Но уж если нравится именно выражение торговая точка, возможны, на мой взгляд, оба варианта. Зависит от значения: если это закрытое помещение, то "в... точке", если открытое, то "на... точке".

Comment: Предложение начинается так: В каждой точке, в которой присутствует продукция...

Comment: А при чём здесь открытое/закрытое помещение?

Answer (score 0):

**На** точке - профессиональный жаргон т. н. "силовых структур" (ср. "на обьекте").

Если вы хотите звучать <strike>как солдафон</strike> брутально - говорите "на точке".

Comment: Пожалуйста без подобных сравнений. И самое главное, логика хромает. Не все, что говорится "структурами", обязательно профжаргон. И не всё, что профжаргон, обязательно плохо и.или неправильно.

Comment: На Вас трудно угодить, уважаемый @behemothus. Вам и "доброе время суток" не понравилось ;)

Comment: *На Вас трудно угодить, уважаемый* - и не мечтайте. Я вообще к лести равнодушен, а уж если дело касается чисто академического спора... ))).  Это политика ресурса, как я её понимаю. одно не соглашаться, но желательно выполнять. А что касается"доброго времени суток", то да, подтверждаю. форма вызывает у многих внутренний протест. Не знаю, где и когда вы это у меня прочитали, но я против использования такого выражения.

Comment: "Community" постоянно подбрасывает старые сообщения вверх. Вчера наткнулся на вопрос про доброе время суток с вашими ответами.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас сложилось, что чаще говорят "на точке", подчеркивая тем самым её конечные геометрические размеры (в математике "точка" - бесконечно малое - и там логичнее "в точке"). Кроме того, выбор предлога может зависеть от контекста. "Дежурство на (торговой) точке" - "купил в торговой точке". Чем сильнее значение "где?", тем интенсивнее "на точке". Ну и, конечно, основополагающее снаружи - внутри (см. Ларf), хотя этот подход со временем все более размывается.

> В каждой точке, в которой присутствует продукция.

Здесь я за "в точке". Но тоже чисто рекомендательно.